# Why should I favour stubs over mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, stubbing

I often read that one should avoid mocks and prefer stubs.

The Isolation Frameworks like FakeItEasy and NSubstitute make it most of the time really easy to mock or stub a dependency. Those frameworks themselves don't distinguish between stubs or mocks, but call them altogether Fakes or Substitutes. As far as I know in the early days of "Mocking" it was very hard to create mock objects, because using the cumbersome Record and Replay mechanism. But today it seems like there is no big difference anymore.

So why should I favor stubs over mocks? Why are mocks more brittle than stubs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't 'prefer' Stubs over Mocks; rather, you should **select the right tool for the job**:

[Mocks for Commands, Stubs for Queries](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/23/mocks-for-commands-stubs-for-queries)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I  should have asked another question. Why do Mocks induce more damage than stubs or why are mocks more brittle then stubs?

Comment: I would expect a better answer from someone with 100K+ rep. For example, you could define the concepts of a "stub" and a "mock" in your own words (link only answers, as you know, are not recommended). The biggest problem with this answer, though, is that it's based on a flawed "mock" definition from an "old" (2007) book, which contradicts what actual mocking libraries provide. Ie, there is a disconnect between theory and practice.

Comment: @Rookian I think the premise for the question is a bit flawed. As Gerard Meszaros explains in that old (apparently useless) book of his, Commands produce *indirect output* instead of the *direct output* produces by Queries. You can often turn indirect output into direct output, and vice versa, so they are actually equivalent. If I have to speculate, people dislike Mocks because they tend to make the Mocks interact too much with each other, but that's more a problem related to doing 'too much' at once, than a problem with Mocks themselves...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Turning indirect output into direct output remembers me on the idea to use messaging where an event is published instead of "calling a void method". You can then verify that the event is in a queue or just in a list of events. See http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2008/02/13/mocks-are-a-code-smell/ Any comments on this idea :) ?

Comment: @Rookian Haven't had the time to (re)read the article, I'm afraid, but that sounds equivalent. Of course, these days, I prefer functional programming, which means that I tend to go the other way, converting indirect output to direct output that represents 'messages' or events.

Answer (score -1):

At least with recent mocking tools, there is no point in bothering with stubs versus mocks. In practice, mock and stubs are the same thing when created by a mocking library. And this is how it should be.

With the mocking libraries available for Java (and for C#.NET too, if I am not mistaken), you can't create "just" a stub. You *always* get a mock object on which expectations can be verified.

Comment: "You always get a mock object on which expectations can be verified" huh? You won't make any verifications on stubs. There is still a difference between both.

Comment: @Rookian Could you point to any mocking library which lets you create just a stub, on which expectations cannot be verified? I am not aware of any such library.

Comment: Such libraries don't create a stub or mock, but a fake object, which can be used as a stub or/and mock.

Comment: @Rookian Which libraries? All the Java mocking libraries do create mocks, not fakes or stubs (I should know, as I created one of them). Maybe in the .NET world things are different, but I guess it's more of a terminology thing than a practical difference.

Comment: In .NET the modern frameworks would produce a fake object also called test double. Dependending on how you use the fake object it is a mock or stub object :) Libraries: FakeItEasy and NSubstitute

Comment: @Rookian Thanks. I looked at [FakeItEasy](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable), but it simply makes a choice of terminology for marketing reasons, by calling everything a "fake". Note this choice is *not consistent* with the definitions given by well-known authors: see [Martin Fowler's definition](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) and [Meszaros' definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double). [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io) simply calls everything a "substitute". So, in fact they confirm what I said, by treating mocks and stubs as basically the same.

Comment: Thre framework treat them as the same for convinience reasons. But I think as Mark Seemann said you still should distinguish both, because you should use stubs for queries and mocks for commands.

Comment: Ok, we don't really disagree I think. The point I am trying to make is only that, in practice, we *don't need to bother choosing between a mock versus a stub* because a test double created with any mocking library can be used either way, depending on what the test needs. A "mock" can be used as "just a stub", and it can also be used to verify "indirect outputs" when applicable.